# Table Division Image and Text vertical Align

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to have an image and text in the same vertical align (Info numbers and mail) but is not working.

I've tried `line-height` of `22px` and `vertical-align` in the `td` but is not working and 
I'm feeling clueless now!

```
<table width="500">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 11px;color: #4C4D4D;line-height:22px;vertical-align:middle;"><p><a href="#" target="_blank" style="margin-right:5px;"><img src="img/Phone-Ico.png" width="22" height="22" alt=""></a>+57 (1) 7026202</p></td>
      <td style="font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 11px;color: #4C4D4D;line-height:22px;vertical-align:middle;"><p><a href="#" target="_blank" style="margin-right:5px; margin-left: 5px;"><img src="img/Whatsapp-Ico.png" width="22" height="22" alt=""></a>+57 (1) 7026202</p></td>
      <td style="font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 11px;color: #4C4D4D;line-height:22px;vertical-align:middle;"><p><a href="#" target="_blank" style="margin-right:5px; margin-left: 5px;"><img src="img/Mail-Ico.png" width="22" height="22" alt=""></a>banano@adsmovil.com</p></td>
      <td style="font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 11px;color: #4C4D4D;line-height:22px;vertical-align:middle;"><p><a href="#" target="_blank" style="margin-right:5px; margin-left: 5px;"><img src="img/Skype-Ico.png" width="22" height="22" alt=""></a>banano2000</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p style="font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 11px;color: #4C4D4D;"> Bogotá, Colombia </p></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[Here's how it looks right now.](http://dalladaniel.com/Test/index.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `vertical-align` property of your images to either `middle` or `bottom`.

For example:

```
a img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: I love YOU! i did not even tought about that your rocks!!! :D thx a lot!